# ComboBox binding returns control type on top of SelectedValue

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, combobox, propertychanged

I have a `ComboBox`:

```
<ComboBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="9" SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedReason}">
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Bug Report" IsSelected="True"/>
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Suggestion"/>
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Complaint"/>
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Other"/>
</ComboBox>
```

...which binds to a `Property`:

```
private string _selectedReason;
public string SelectedReason
{
    get { return _selectedReason; }
    set
    {
        if (_selectedReason == value)
        {
            return;
        }

        _selectedReason = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("SelectedReason");
    }
}
```

When I output the `value`, instead of showing something like:

```
Bug Report
Suggestion
```

...I get:

```
System.Windows.Controls.ComboBoxItem: Bug Report
System.Windows.Controls.ComboBoxItem: Suggestion
```

I tried using `SelectedItem` instead, but the result is the same.  All I want is the value and not the control type.  Any ideas what's going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set `SelectedValuePath` to `Content` :

```
<ComboBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="9" SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedReason}" 
        SelectedValuePath="Content">
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Bug Report" IsSelected="True"/>
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Suggestion"/>
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Complaint"/>
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Other"/>
</ComboBox>
```